# send file to server

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, file-upload

HTML

```
<input type="file" id="file1" />
```

SCRIPT

```
file=$("#file1");

            $.ajax({
             type: "POST",
             url: "Allcammand.aspx?cmd=EnterProduct&idCompany="+getParam("idCompany"),
             type:"post",
             data: {
                 file: file
              },
                async: false ,
                   success: function(response){                                                                   
                    },
                    error:function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){alert(xhr.responseText); ShowMessage("خطا در انتقال اطلاعات شرکت","fail");}
            });
```

This is true whether the file transfer.

in `Allcammand.aspx` how can get file?????

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery Ajax File Upload](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2320069/jquery-ajax-file-upload)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uploading files via AJAX is a complex process that you probably aren't going to want to write yourself. I'd recommend using something like this: http://jquery.malsup.com/form/